# fetch date data from the table so that i can use for carbon diffInDays()

Tags: php, eloquent, php-carbon, laravel-query-builder

I want to get the date_start_raise of the `cycles` table so that I can make chicken age by using carbon diffInDays()

MortalityController.php:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
    'date_input' => 'required|date',
    'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
    ) );

        $cycle = Cycle::select('id')
        ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
        ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
        ->get();

        $id = 0;
        foreach($cycle as $value){
            $id = $value->id;
        }

        $dateStart = Cycle::select('date_start_raise')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
        ->get();

        $start = Carbon::now() ;
        $input = new Carbon($request->get('date_input'));
        foreach($dateStart as $value){
            $start = $value->start;
        }

        $chickenAge = $start->diffInDays($input) ;

    return Mortality::create([
        'date_input' => request('date_input'),
        'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
        'chicken_age' => $chickenAge,
        'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
        'cycle_id'  => $id,
        'user_id'  => Auth::id()
    ]);
```

but i have an error it says that

> "Call to a member function diffInDays() on null"

the $start is null.

**How can i get the date_start_raise in `cycles` table**?

Comment: Try to print $start and $request->get('date_input')

Comment: the $start is null. how can i fetch the date data from ta table ?

Comment: $start is not taking from the database. It is the current time.right?

Comment: yes for define and it will use to foreach to get the data

Comment: There is a problem in your code.The variable you declared in all foreach will able to take last assigned data.Because its not an array

Comment: how fix it or how can i get the data that i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$start = $value->start;` should be `$start = $value->data_start_raise;`

I don't know what framework for your, but usually if all you need only 1 row may can try first(), getFirst() or get('first'), and I think you can use `Cycle::select('id', 'data_start_raise')` and add order by condition there, then can save second query.

I don't know what is Carbon::now(), but I think your logic like:

```
$date = '2018-12-25';
$obj = Carbon::now();
$offset = $obj->diffInDays($date);
```

first time, you defined $start = Carbon::now(); but in the foreach, you overwrite $start as one date string, so diffInDays() not a method of one string.

**Updated**

```
<?php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
    'date_input' => 'required|date',
    'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
    ) );

    $cycle = Cycle::select('id', 'date_start_raise')
        ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
        ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
        ->orderBy('date_end_raise desc') //not sure, I've never used laravel
        ->limit(1) //not sure, I've never used laravel
        ->get();

    $id = 0;
    $chickenAge = 0;
    foreach($cycle as $value){
        $id = $value->id;
    }
    if ($id) {
        $start = new Carbon($value->date_start_raise);
        $chickenAge = $start->diffInDays(request('date_input')) ;
    }

    return Mortality::create([
        'date_input' => request('date_input'),
        'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
        'chicken_age' => $chickenAge,
        'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
        'cycle_id'  => $id,
        'user_id'  => Auth::id()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: i use laravel sir

Comment: I just updated, please focus on my comment, I can't sure them ok for laravel, but I think you can fix it.

Comment: thre was an error `"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id, date_start_raise' in 'field list'`

Comment: try select('id', 'date_start_raise') or select(['id', 'date_start_raise'])

Comment: it works please edit the answer for educational purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It will save the Mortality within the foreach itself

```
  public function store(Request $request)
     {
                $this->validate($request, array(
                'date_input' => 'required|date',
                'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
                ) );

                    $cycle = Cycle::select('id')
                    ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
                    ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
                    ->get();

                    $id = 0;
                    foreach($cycle as $value){
                        $id = $value->id;
                        $dateStart = Cycle::select('date_start_raise')
                                          ->where('id','=',$id)
                                          ->first();   
                        $start = Carbon::now() ;
                        $input = new Carbon($request->get('date_input'));
                        $a = $dateStart->date_start_raise;
                        $start = Carbon::parse($a);
                        $chickenAge = $start->diffInDays($input) ;
                        return Mortality::create([
                         'date_input' => request('date_input'),
                         'number_of_mortality' => request('number_of_mortality'),
                         'chicken_age' => $chickenAge,
                         'cause_of_death' => request('cause_of_death'),
                         'cycle_id'  => $id,
                         'user_id'  => Auth::id()
                       ]);
                  }
   }
```

Comment: Did you tried this code?Actually this function only needs one foreach

Comment: i try but there was an error `"Call to a member function diffInDays() on null"`

Comment: I edited my answer.                        $start = $dateStart->date_start_raise;

Comment: there was an error  `Call to a member function diffInDays() on string`

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now try this. I converted the string to date

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
        'date_input' => 'required|date',
        'number_of_mortality' => 'required|numeric',
        ) );

        $cycle = Cycle::select('id', 'date_start_raise')
            ->where('date_start_raise','<=',$request->get('date_input'))
            ->where('date_end_raise','>=',$request->get('date_input'))
            ->get();

        $id = 0;
        $chickenAge = 0;
        $input= Carbon::parse($request->get('date_input'));
        foreach($cycle as $value){
            $id = $value->id;
        }
        if ($id) {
            $start = Carbon::parse($value->date_start_raise);
            $chickenAge = $start->diffInDays($input) ;
        }
```

This is the code